# PHP - session flash message not carried over on redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have done a search, and so far none of the answers I've seen on this site answer my question - I will be happy if someone could point me to a duplicate that answers :)

That being said, I believe the issue is relatively simple.

I am custom building a CMS system in PHP (and some MySQL, but that's not needed for this). I have done something similar for a college course and came across the same issue - and the professor dismissed it as "fine" since he didn't have time to look into the resolution.

All I want to do is to set a Flash message via session variable to the index on user log in. The flash works great on same page, but on redirect, nothing is carried over in the array. On my "similar class project" the exact same code worked fine between some pages, but not between others - so I know it's capable of moving with the redirect - it just simply refuses to.

**EDIT:** It should be noted that any other session variables set in the same piece of code transfer on redirect - just NOT 'flash'. I have updated the code below to reflect. I have also added session_start() to my letmein.php file per suggestion, but could someone confirm this necessity if it is only a library file referenced by a page that already has session_start() declared?

Here is all my code:

*key.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

$title = "STH Liquidations";
$description = "Product wholesale";
$keywords = "wholesale, product, pallets";

require "scripts/letmein.php";

include "parts/_head.php";
include "parts/header.php";
?>

    <div id="key">

        <form id="pass" method="post" action="key.php">

            <label for="password">Key: </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Let Me In!" class="unlock">

        </form>


    </div>

<?php
include "parts/footer.php";
?>
```

*scripts/letmein.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

$result = false;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($_POST['password'] == "password removed")
    {
        $result = true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

        $_SESSION['flash'] = "You have been logged in. IP Address: ".$ip;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['flash'] = "Log In Failed. Please try again...";
    }
}



?>
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

$title = "STH Liquidations";
$description = "Product wholesale";
$keywords = "wholesale, product, pallets";

include "parts/_head.php";
include "parts/header.php";
include "parts/nav.php";

print_r($_SESSION);
?>

        <div id="content">

            <div class="about">
                This is where information "about us" will go.
            </div>


            content goes here



        </div>

<?php
include "parts/footer.php";
?>
```

*parts/header.php*

```
<!-- =============== -->
<!--       BODY      -->
<!-- =============== -->
<body>


<div id="header">

    <!-- TITLE -->
    <div class="headerwindow">
        <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
    </div>




</div>

<!-- FLASH MESSAGES -->
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['flash']))
{
    echo "<div class='flash'>" . $_SESSION['flash'] ."</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
?>


    <!-- CONTENT TO WRAP 2 COL STYLE -->
    <div id="main">
```

**OUTPUT IN THE PRINT_R: Array ( [logged_in] => 1 )**

Comment: Note that the key.php in the first code block is the file name and not actually part of the code. This site thought that the key.php written above the code was "code not properly formatted" and wouldn't let me post it outside of the code block.

Comment: I was able to modify it for you @Christina Kline.

Comment: Don't forget to call `session_start()` in letmein.php

Comment: I just tried, made no change. However, letmein.php is just a library - it's being referenced by a page that already has session_start() declared - it shouldn't need a second declaration, right?